# Condition on a matrix sum with equal determinant and trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n$ be a positive integer, $J$ the matrix of all ones and $Q$ a symmetric  positive semidefinite matrix such that

- $\det(nI-Q) = \det(Q+J)$
- $\rm{tr}(nI-Q) = \rm{tr}(Q+J)$

and also

- $nI-Q \ne Q+J.$

Are there any other properties of $Q$ that can be deduced from the above constraints?

I hope the question is not too shallow. I stumbled upon this while studying a unrelated problem and I am curious to see if there if there is anything more that can be said about $Q$ from these facts alone.

Comment: Isn't the second $\bullet$ mistyped? Isn't it ${\rm tr}(nI-Q)={\rm tr}(Q+J)$?

Comment: @berci Indeed. I have now corrected the question

Comment: Well $n^2 - tr(Q)=ntr(I)-tr(Q)=tr(nI-Q)=tr(Q+J)=tr(Q)+tr(J) = tr(Q)+n$ so $tr(Q)=\cfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $Q$ be $m\times m$. Two obvious properties are $\mathrm{tr}(Q)=\frac{m(n-1)}2$ and $0\le\lambda_\min\le\frac{\mathrm{tr}(Q)}{m}=\frac{(n-1)}2\le\lambda_\max\le n$.